# Show event names on month view in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

It's just square dots and lines of your choice of color. Are there any options or ways to get it to show the event's text in the month view as it does in the week/agenda/etc?

Edit:

Apparently month view was stripped out of the latest store version. I don't understand how a calendar could be better without the ability to see the whole month (or at least the option to) as you would on a wall but so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar doesn't have that feature.

You can use a 3rd party app like aCalendar instead ([paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendarplus)/[free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar)).

[image]

Comment: I don't consider this an option since it is not free.

Comment: @Enigma The free version is aCalendar: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar&hl=en

Comment: Oh good. I'll leave this unanswered for a while just in case Google comes through.

Answer (score 1):

[Jorte Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.johospace.jorte&hl=en) is a free alternative that offers this functionality. It also synchronizes with Google calendar both ways.

It looks normal by default and the icons only get added if you want them there.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't an option in the Google Calendar app. However, you could:

1. Open a browser and go to http://calendar.google.com/
2. Scroll to the bottom and click the "Desktop" link for "View"
3. Zoom in to see what you want

Note that all the features might not work depending on the browser, but Chrome Mobile seems to do pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

On 23 April 2015, Google Calendar was updated with the return on Month view.

> See even more events at a glance with Month view on phones

On top of that, the current version also displays the event name instead of square dots and lines.

Note, however, that it only works on portrait mode. The landscape mode only displays in Week view.